# How do I get the Windows 8 Desktop to stop refreshing itself while I'm working?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, refresh-rate, desktop-icons

I have an Asus touchscreen laptop with Windows 8, not RT. The best way that I can describe the problem is: when I am working on something in the desktop, the desktop/screen refreshes itself. It doesn't matter if I am using an IE window, or Word, etc.

Basically, while I'm viewing the desktop, the icons disappear for a second or two and then come back. If I'm typing in Word, the screen essentially pauses and just stops typing. It won't start typing again until I touch the screen or click on something. In IE, the screen acts pretty similar, if I happen to be typing a URL, or in a form, etc.

Why does it do this? And how can I make it stop? Thanks so much for any help you can give me, and please let me know if I can provide any other info that you think may be helpful.

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem. Have you updated all your drivers since you installed Windows 8? You don't have to mention your not running Windows RT because Windows RT is not Windows 8, while it shares the same core, its not sold by itself and cannot be installed on any old machine on a shelf.

Answer (score 0):

On my system I turned off the "Mozy Home Status" utility and the constant refreshing stopped.  If you're using Mozy perhaps this will fix the problem on your system as well. If not, check your other Startup programs. Good luck.

Comment: Please expand your answer by providing more details how the software you're suggesting answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem but it was because of repeated disconnection/connection of a removable device. Explorer would refresh each minute.
In my case, it was a faulty USB connector which was causing the disconnection.
If that's not your case, it maybe a driver issue. Go to start and type **Event Viewer** to open event viewer.
Check which driver is malfunctioning then either update or disable it.